# How can I cancel a thread's current task and reset the thread to a known good state without any dynamic allocations on Linux + GLibc?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, posix

I want to cancel a thread's current task and reset the thread to a
known good state in a very reliable way.  I plan to use `mlockall` and
already preallocate my threads so when I mean reliable I mean
**really** reliable.  The traditional POSIX solution is to use
`pthread_cancel` to cancel and destroy the thread and then to create a
new replacement thread. However, this solution allocates user stacks
dynamically with `mmap` (well, GLibc caches thread stacks but this
could change at any time), and allocates kernel stacks dynamically
with `clone`; and these system calls could fail with errors at any
time so this solution does not work for me.

Comment: I usually just sidestep such an issue by setting some boolean 'abort' flag that instructs the thread to terminate itself, (whenever it gets around to checking the flag), setting the thread to the lowest possible priority, forgetting about it and starting another thread.  The old thread will die, eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an answer that works with blocking system calls. It's really ugly but it avoids several tricky racy conditions.

First, one registers an empty signal handler for some signal (**don't use a real-time signal for this**, those can queue up an trap the thread were waiting for in a never ending barrage of signals):

```
    {
        struct sigaction act = { 0 };
        sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
        act.sa_handler = do_nothing;
        if (-1 == sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL)) {
            perror("sigaction");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

// ..

static void do_nothing(int signo)
{
}
```

Then for cancelling one loops sending a signal to the thread doing the operation and polling to see if the thread has cancelled the operation.

```
void linted_asynch_task_cancel(struct linted_asynch_task *task)
{
    int errnum;

    errnum = pthread_mutex_lock(&task->owner_lock);
    if (errnum != 0) {
        assert(errnum != EDEADLK);
        assert(false);
    }

    task->cancelled = true;

    /* Yes, really, we do have to busy wait to prevent race
     * conditions unfortunately */
    while (task->owned) {
        errnum = pthread_kill(task->owner, SIGUSR1);
        if (errnum != 0 && errnum != EAGAIN) {
            assert(errnum != ESRCH);
            assert(errnum != EINVAL);
            assert(false);
        }

        errnum = pthread_mutex_unlock(&task->owner_lock);
        if (errnum != 0) {
            assert(errnum != EPERM);
            assert(false);
        }

        sched_yield();

        errnum = pthread_mutex_lock(&task->owner_lock);
        if (errnum != 0) {
            assert(errnum != EDEADLK);
            assert(false);
        }
    }
    errnum = pthread_mutex_unlock(&task->owner_lock);
    if (errnum != 0) {
        assert(errnum != EPERM);
        assert(false);
    }
}
```

The for the actual thread doing the task one simply resubmits a task on EINTR:

```
static void run_task_sleep_until(struct linted_asynch_pool *pool,
                                 struct linted_asynch_task *task)
{
    struct linted_asynch_task_sleep_until *task_sleep = task->data;
    int errnum = 0;

    int flags = task_sleep->flags;

    if (-1 == clock_nanosleep(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, flags, &task_sleep->request,
                              &task_sleep->request)) {
        errnum = errno;
        assert(errnum != 0);
    }

    if (EINTR == errnum) {
        linted_asynch_pool_submit(pool, task);
        return;
    }

    task->errnum = errnum;

    linted_asynch_pool_complete(pool, task);
}
```

Finally, in the resubmission function one checks to see if the operation has been cancelled and then completes if with the `ECANCELED` error if it has:

```
void linted_asynch_pool_submit(struct linted_asynch_pool *pool,
                               struct linted_asynch_task *task)
{
    bool cancelled;
    int errnum;

    assert(pool != NULL);
    assert(!pool->stopped);

    errnum = pthread_mutex_lock(&task->owner_lock);
    if (errnum != 0) {
        assert(errnum != EDEADLK);
        assert(false);
    }

    task->owned = false;
    cancelled = task->cancelled;

    errnum = pthread_mutex_unlock(&task->owner_lock);
    if (errnum != 0) {
        assert(errnum != EPERM);
        assert(false);
    }

    if (cancelled) {
        task->errnum = ECANCELED;
        linted_queue_send(pool->event_queue, LINTED_UPCAST(task));
    } else {
        linted_queue_send(pool->worker_command_queue,
                          LINTED_UPCAST(task));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just arbitrarily 'reset' a thread of execution to a 'good' state.  If you could, we would all be able to fix hung programs by doing so. The only things that can seriously influence a running thread are boolean atomic flags that the thread/task has to check or the OS, (which can always terminate threads).

If you don't want to continually create/stop/terminate threads, (a very good idea indeed), while maintaining some 'task cancellation' functionality, then the thread in question must be signaled somehow to stop running its task and go back to looking for the next one, (eg. on an input producer-consumer queue).  If the task is CPU-intensive, you are going to need an atomic 'abort' boolean in the task that is checked at some reasonable frequency.  The task can then exit early and allow the thread to get back to the PC-queue, (or whatever feeds it its tasks).  If the task has a field that its executing thread can set with its ID, it is possible that the priority of the thread executing the task could be lowered at the same time as the abort bool is set.  An oversupply of pooled threads could then ensure that the thread running the aborting task would not interfere with the running of other 'good' tasks.   The thread would have to ensure that it raises its priority again after a task exit, so it's ready for the next good task.

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer how to reset threads that are stuck in some blocking system call like `sigwaitinfo` or `waitid`.